# Angular says : The webpack.config.js file already exists

Tags: webpack, angular-cli

When I run `ng eject` I get the following error

```
The webpack.config.js file already exists.
```

What's the equivalent of `make clean` using Angular?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng` provides a `--force` option

```
--force (Boolean) Overwrite any webpack.config.js and npm scripts already existing.
```